# Entity Framework core multiple foreign keys same table error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

i have looked at a ton of previous posts on how to have multiple foreign keys from the same table but I cant seem to get it working, even though my code seems identical to these posts.  As far as I can tell, the below should work.

My User model

```
public string Name{get;set;}
public ICollection<UserOwnership> Slaves { get; set; }  //Users this user owns
public ICollection<UserOwnership> Masters { get; set; }  //Users that own this user
```

My user ownership model

```
public class UserOwnership
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MasterUserId { get; set; }
    public int SlaveUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Master { get; set; }
    public virtual User Slave { get; set; }
}
```

UserOwnership mapping

```
public class UserOwnershipMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserOwnership>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserOwnership> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("UserOwnership");
            builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Id });

            builder.HasOne(e => e.Master).WithMany(e => e.Slaves).HasForeignKey(e => e.MasterUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // one master many slaves
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Slave).WithMany(e => e.Masters).HasForeignKey(e => e.SlaveUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // one slave many masters
        }
    }
```

my error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'User.Slaves' of type 'ICollection<UserOwnership>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: To me the exception indicates that the shown fluent configuration code is not executed - did you forget to call `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserOwnershipMapping())` or `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(...)` from your `OnModelCreating` override?

Comment: can you post code that does the model setup?

Comment: @IvanStoev Seems like that was the problem. Forgot to add my on modelcreating override. Thanks!